# Jade - subsequent lines becoming children of included partial?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, brunch

I am having issues with a simple jade layout, for example:

```
include test.jade
#bar hi
```

and in `test.jade`

```
#foo hello
```

And no matter what, the `#bar` is always rendered as a child of `#foo`.

```
<div id="foo">hello
  <div id="bar">hi</div>
</div>
```

When I am trying to achieve

```
<div id="foo">hello</div>
<div id="bar">hi</div>
```

I'm confused if I'm doing something wrong or if this is the intended behaviour of jade?

I am building my jade templates with [brunch](http://brunch.io) and [static-jade-brunch](https://github.com/ilkosta/static-jade-brunch) so I'm not sure if that is where the problem lies or if I am missing something?

Comment: Looks like a _brunch_ issue, your first example works fine using Jade directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, okay, I'm not sure if this is the right solution, but I found I had to wrap the include in a block:

```
block test
  include test.jade
#foo hello
```

and I have the desired output.